# how to get a stored _setting property value in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, yii

passed php variable to js function

I want to take below mentioned variable($hod_verify) to use in javascript for that I used following code in php to pass that function using Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript() and want to read that value in js script.For testing purpose .used alert() function to view that variable,bt it's not given that value

```
<?php 
if($model->IsApproved_hod==0){
$hod_verify=array('tru'=>'hi'); 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(__CLASS__.'#storevariable',                                                                                                                                                                                   
"storevariable.init($hod_verify);", CClientScript::POS_READY);
}
?>
```

How to read hod_verify variable value in this js function?

```
(function( storevariable, $, undefined ) {
// guard to detect browser-specific issues early in development
"use strict";
// private var
var _settings;
// public var
storevariable.someProperty = 'default value';
// public method
storevariable.init = function(settings) {
_settings = $.extend({},settings);
alert(_settings);
//storevariable.someProperty1 = 'settings';    
}
}( window.storevariable = window.storevariable || {}, jQuery ));
```

Comment: I do not exaclty get what you are doing, but don;t you have a problem with naming a function "storevariable" and then also a variable with the same name?

Comment: i want to take above mentioned variable($hod_verify) to use in javascript for that i used preceding code in php to pass that function using Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript() and want to read that value in js script.For testing purpose .used alert() funtion to view that variable,bt it's not give that value.

Comment: did you get my problem?

Comment: if `$hod_verify` is an array, you should probabaly use `json_encode($hod_verify)` to get a proper object out of it, then in you code it should be accessible -  `storevariable.tru = 'hi'` in your case

Comment: but I don not know how the rest of your script works.. I would do it via simple javascript, with a global variable, just echoing out `echo '<script type="text/javascript> var storevariable = '.json_encode($storevariable).';' </script>`